# objective-c: variable is not a CFString, how to correctly assign string value to an object's property?

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
- (IBAction)start:(UIButton *)sender {
  NSString *t=@"123";   // line 1
  self.detailDescriptionLabel.text=t;
}
```

The syntax check is correct, but when I build and run it on iphone, it breaks out at line 1 and sending the error message like "variable is not a CFString"

How to solve this problem?

And it is working when I wrote this:

```
- (IBAction)start:(UIButton *)sender {
  self.detailDescriptionLabel.text=nil;
}
```

I really think the problem lies in how to correctly assign a string constant to a UILabel's text property.

Comment: is detailDescriptionLabel an actual UILabel?

Comment: yes it is an actual UILabel, actually, even I delete that line, the error still exists.

Comment: Maybe your detailDescriptionLabel is completely released. Without more code I think it'll be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it is stupid... I wrongly pressed the shotcut key and a breakpoint to it.....So actually there is no mistakes in the code, just my mistake in the XCode IDE.